# possible to Java override functions at an instance level?

Tags: java

I'm reviewing some Java code written long ago and not being a Java developer, I have a question. I found the following lines in the body of a class. Someone is creating an instance of SearchQueryParameter however there are curly braces following "new SearchQueryParameter" and it appears that someone overrode some functions here.

My questions are the following.

1) Are these functions overwritten at an instance level?

2) Does this language feature have a name?

```
public static final SearchQueryParameter X_POSTDOC_WORKFLOW_STEP = new SearchQueryParameter(128,"XPOSTDOCWorkflowStep",AdvancedFields.X_EVENT_POSTDOC_WFSTEP,SearchTypes.XEVENT_DOCUMENTS) {

    @Override
    protected int getFilterType() {
        return SEARCH_FILTER;
    }

    <<snip>>
};
```

Thanks, mj

Comment: It's an instance of an anonymous subclass. It's not exactly "overridden at an instance level", but it pretty much acts like it, because you have exactly one instance of that subclass, and you can't create any more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Background:

This is called [anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html). It is a class that extends a non `final` class or implements a single interface and you're creating a single instance of this class.

Now, to your questions:

> 1) Are these functions overwritten at an instance level?

No, they are at level class. You have a new subclass of the desired class and this subclass overrides the method. Then, you create a new instance of the subclass.

> 2) Does this language feature have a name?

Yes, it is anonymous class.

Comment: The function is overridden at an instance level and a class level, not one or the other; while a new class definition is being created, another instance of that definition can never be created. (which you don't mention.)

Comment: @APerson in Java, by definition, a reference value (the instance) cannot define any method, so an instance cannot override the method. It is the anonymous class which overrides the method, and then you have an instance of this class.

Comment: @APerson You can create a new instance of the anonymous class if you want. (YOLO REFLECTION)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis That's true, but reflection is needed to get another instance.

Answer (score 0):

The code creates an instance of an anonymous class (`SearchQueryParameter`) and then overrides one method in it.

Essentially, it creates *something* that extends the `SearchQueryParameter` class and which overrides the `getFilterType()` method.

Since only one instance of this particular class definition can ever be created (without reflection), the function may appear like it's being overridden at an instance level but is actually getting overridden at the class level (since it may replace the existing definition).

It's called an [anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

Comment: *the function is being overridden at an instance level* this isn't true. An object reference cannot define any method at all. Methods are only defined in classes, and here you have an instance of an anonymous class, and the anonymous class overrides the method, not the instance.

Comment: Updated answer to reflect (badum-tss) that.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should have done some research on your own first, but that is called an anonymous inner class.

Comment: This is not at instance level. It's a new class which overrides the method in parent class, and you're creating an instance of this new subclass.

Comment: Indeed, it is important to realize that while anonymous sub-classes create a 'feel' of instance-level overriding, they don't really do that. Calling getClass() on the instance reveals a different class name!